# Need help in optimizing update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables :

```
create table CurrentDay (
ID int identity primary key,
ssn varchar(10), 
val money, 
CheckDate datetime, 
CurrentStatus tinyint)

create table PreviousDay (
ID int identity primary key,
ssn varchar(10), 
val money, 
CheckDate datetime, 
CurrentStatus tinyint)
```

I need update field CurrentDay.CurrentStatus with this values:

- 111,if in the PreviousDay.ssn is the same ssn as in the CurrentDay and if the PreviousDay's  val is the same as in the CurrentDay;
- 112,if in the PreviousDay.ssn is the same  as in the CurrentDay and if the PreviousDay's  val is bigger as in the CurrentDay;
- 113,if in the PreviousDay.ssn  is the same as in the CurrentDay and if the PreviousDay's  val is smaller as in the CurrentDay;
- 114,if in there is not PreviousDay.ssn the same as in the CurrentDay i.e. the ssn in CurrentDay only (it is today's info) .

I'd wrote some query,but i it is desirable to find other way for doing this task using only one join between PreviousDay and CurrentDay tables. Obviously,that this isn't a very lucky kind...Here is my variant:

```
Update CurrentDay 
Set CurrentStatus=case
when exists (select PreviousDay.ID from PreviousDay 
where PreviousDay.ssn=CurrentDay.ssn AND 
PreviousDay.val=CurrentDay.val  AND
PreviousDay.CheckDate=DATEADD(day,-1,CurrentDay.CheckDate))
then 111
when exists (select PreviousDay.ID from PreviousDay 
where PreviousDay.ssn=CurrentDay.ssn AND 
PreviousDay.val>CurrentDay.val  AND
PreviousDay.CheckDate=DATEADD(day,-1,CurrentDay.CheckDate))
then 112
when exists (select PreviousDay.ID from PreviousDay 
where PreviousDay.ssn=CurrentDay.ssn AND 
PreviousDay.val<CurrentDay.val  AND
PreviousDay.CheckDate=DATEADD(day,-1,CurrentDay.CheckDate))
then 113
when exists (select PreviousDay.ID from PreviousDay 
where PreviousDay.ssn!=CurrentDay.ssn AND 
PreviousDay.CheckDate=DATEADD(day,-1,CurrentDay.CheckDate))
then 114
end;
```

Here is other query,but in that case i cannot update CurrentDay.CurrentStatus' fieid with value 114 because there is only matching rows on ssn in both tables:

`Set Currentday.CurrentStatus=(select 111 where   PreviousDay.val=CurrentDay.val union all select 112 where and PreviousDay.val>CurrentDay.val 
union all select 113 where and PreviousDay.val<CurrentDay.val /*union all select 114 */ )
from PreviousDay join CurrentDay on PreviousDay.ssn=CurrentDay.ssn and  PreviousDay.CheckDate=DATEADD(day,-1,CurrentDay.CheckDate)`

Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
UPDATE
    C
Set
    CurrentStatus = CASE
            WHEN P.val = C.val THEN 111
            WHEN P.val > C.val THEN 112
            WHEN P.val < C.val THEN 113
            ELSE 114 ---this works because if P.VAL is null, that is no matching row
        END
FROM
    CurrentDay C
    LEFT JOIN
    PreviousDay P On C.ssn = P.ssn AND P.CheckDate = DATEADD(day, -1, C.CheckDate))
```

Comment: I'd recommend being explicit on the 114 - Status 114 means the SSN didn't exist the previous day, so it should say "WHEN P.val IS NULL"; This is better for someone later on reading the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
UPDATE CurrentDay 
        SET CurrentStatus =
        CASE 
            WHEN cd.val = pd.val THEN 111
            WHEN cd.val < pd.val THEN 112
            WHEN cd.val > pd.val THEN 113
            WHEN pd.val IS NULL THEN 114
        END
FROM    CurrentDay cd LEFT JOIN
        PreviousDay pd ON   cd.ssn = pd.ssn
                        AND cd.CheckDate = DATEADD(d, 1, pd.CheckDate)
```

This was my test code. Play around with the **val** entries for PreviousDay to see if it works, or completely remove the entry for PreviousDay to see the new Entry option.

```
DECLARE  @CurrentDay table (
ID int identity primary key,
ssn varchar(10), 
val money, 
CheckDate datetime, 
CurrentStatus tinyint)



DECLARE @PreviousDay table (
ID int identity primary key,
ssn varchar(10), 
val money, 
CheckDate datetime, 
CurrentStatus tinyint)

INSERT INTO @CurrentDay (ssn, val, CheckDate)  SELECT 1, 1, '02 Jan 2009'
INSERT INTO @PreviousDay (ssn, val, CheckDate)  SELECT 1, 0, '01 Jan 2009'

UPDATE @CurrentDay 
        SET CurrentStatus =
        CASE 
            WHEN cd.val = pd.val THEN 111
            WHEN cd.val < pd.val THEN 112
            WHEN cd.val > pd.val THEN 113
            WHEN pd.val IS NULL THEN 114
        END
FROM    @CurrentDay cd LEFT JOIN
        @PreviousDay pd ON  cd.ssn = pd.ssn
                        AND cd.CheckDate = DATEADD(d, 1, pd.CheckDate)

SELECT * FROM @CurrentDay
```

Comment: Same comment as for gbn - should be explicit on the 114 code (include the NULL check).  I could have sworn you had the NULL check when I upvoted, now it is not.

Comment: Changed it, something like that?

Comment: It would function correctly either way, just self documenting with the NULL check.